# How to variable stored hash table information about a SQL result in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, hashtable

Scenario:  I am trying to fetch a bunch of files from SFTP and then iterate through them to compare the file parameters to those in my Audit table and if its a totally new file then I insert the info in the audit table.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
 $directory = $session.ListDirectory("/broken/")
$session.Dispose()

foreach ($fileInfo in $directory.Files)
    {
        $FileName  = $($fileInfo.Name)
        $FileSize = $($fileInfo.Length)
        $DateModified = $($fileInfo.LastWriteTime)
        
        If($FileName  -eq '.' -or $FileName -eq '..' )
        {
         continue
        }
         
        #Check if file was downloaded earlier  
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $SQLUsername; Password = $SQLPassword"
        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT [FileName],[DateModified],[FileSize] FROM [FTP].[dbo].[Log] WHERE FileName='$FileName'"
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
        $SqlConnection.Close()
        $Result = $DataSet.Tables[0]
        ####
```

Now that I have the SQL query information fetch into my PowerShell hash table variable.
How do I then compare if the results were returned or not

I have tried doing a few things as follow:

```
If ($Result.Matches.Count -ne 0 ){
            ### Naming the files 
            $SQLFTPFileName = $Result.RemoteFileName[0]
            $SQLFTPFileDateModified = $Result.DateModified[0]
            $SQLFTPFileSize = $Result.FileSize[0]
            ###
OR

If ($Result.RemoteFileName[0] -ne 0 ){
            ### Naming the files 
            $SQLFTPFileName = $Result.RemoteFileName[0]
            $SQLFTPFileDateModified = $Result.DateModified[0]
            $SQLFTPFileSize = $Result.FileSize[0]
            ###


            }
```

Can you please assist me here?

Thank you for the help, appreciated.

Comment: The code is missing the final `}`. Furthermore, in the loop you are setting a local variable over and over with `$Result = $DataSet.Tables[0]`, but your loop never outputs anything. To capture the output, do `$Result = foreach ($fileInfo in $directory.Files) { .. }` and in the final lines of the loop output the result with just `$DataSet.Tables[0]`, followed by `$DataSet.Dispose()`

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your response
Actually there lot more logic ahead in the foreach loop.
I did end that loop just that I have included all the code here. 

I am still not sure how can I check if the variable $result is null/0.

Comment: Well... That doesn't matter. You are not outputting the $Result in the loop.. My comment still stands I believe.

Comment: Sorry but I am bit unable understand here

At this moment my $Result variable holds 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Result

RemoteFileName DateModified         FileSize
-------------- ------------         --------
local.txt      1/24/2020 2:21:11 AM     2582 


But this expression  If ($Result.Matches.Count -ne 0 ) comes out to be FALSE 
I am expecting it to be TRUE, since it contains a value.

Thank you

Comment: And if I compare it with   IF($Result.RemoteFileName[0] -ne 0 )
then incase of empty value if complains about null array.

Please suggest a way out of this

Comment: My Question is: 

What expression can I use for it to compare in the  IF condition? 

  $SqlConnection.Close()
            $Result = $DataSet.Tables[0] 
            ####  
            If ($Result.Matches.Count -ne 0 )